# Reset Font Awesome icon to original icon on click

Tags: jquery

As you can see in the demo, initially, i see only arrow down (fa-angle-down). If i click on any of those, the icon is replaced with arrow up (fa-angle-up).
If i leave it arrow up and than i click on another arrow down, the arrow up that i left is replaced with arrow down. All fine till now.

The problem i have is how to change (reset) the arrow up icon to default arrow down if i click again on it because right now if i click on it it will not reset.

This is part of a accordion menu that shows partial content on click.
I could use toggle to change the icon but toggle seems to work only if you have 1 icon (while keeping the exiting functionality).

This is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/Adyyda/cnkzeym7/4/

And this is the code

```
<span class="has-subnav fa fa-angle-down"></span>
<span class="has-subnav fa fa-angle-down"></span>
<span class="has-subnav fa fa-angle-down"></span>
<span class="has-subnav fa fa-angle-down"></span>

span.has-subnav {

    display: block;
    font-size: 17px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #f00;
    background: rgba(205, 205, 205, 0.2);
    top: 1px;
    width:50px;
    height: 50px;

}

$('span.has-subnav').click(function() {
    $('span.has-subnav').removeClass('fa-angle-up').addClass('fa-angle-down'); 
    $(this).removeClass('fa-angle-down').addClass('fa-angle-up'); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var $subnavs = $('span.has-subnav').on('click', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  
  //it's down, change it up
  if ($this.hasClass('fa-angle-down')) {
    //change the one clicked
    $this.removeClass('fa-angle-down').addClass('fa-angle-up');
    //reset all the others that were clicked
    $subnavs.not(this).removeClass('fa-angle-up').addClass('fa-angle-down');
  } else {
    //just reset the one clicked
    $this.addClass('fa-angle-down').removeClass('fa-angle-up');
  }
});
```

You could also condense it with toggleClass().

```js
var $subnavs = $('span.has-subnav').on('click', function() {
  //reset the other elements
  $subnavs.not(this).removeClass('fa-angle-up').addClass('fa-angle-down');
  //change the one clicked, toggling the classes back and forth
  $(this).toggleClass('fa-angle-up fa-angle-down');
});
```